# What does ここはどことも知れぬどこででもある国 mean

Tags: grammar, translation, words, sentence, anime

The person is narrating a stage play.

> とくとご覧あれ ～ ！‌
> **ここはどことも知れぬどこででもある国‌**。勤勉質素を奨励するおもしろみのない王様が国を治めておりまし た‌。

The part that confuses me the most is "どことも知れぬ". As for the part that follows, I think it roughly means "a country that could be anywhere".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "どことも知れぬ" means "No one knows where" or something like that. "どこででもある" is "can be anywhere".

If I were to translate this, I would translate it to "This is a country of everywhere and nowhere". Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I'm still quite confused by the "とも". It would be really helpful if you could break down the phrase by grammar points.

Comment: "ともなく" is a word used here. It's called *連語* (collocation), refers to how words go together or form fixed relationships(e.g. heavy rain/大雨, discharge/放電, etc). Anyway, "ともなく" means that you(or someone else) are not sure about something. For example, "a person appeared out of nowhere" is easy to understand.